# MySQL - How to get a 0 when COUNT(*) returns null?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm haing some difficulties with an SQL request.
In that request, I wanna get, for a week (entered in parameter), and a year (also in parameter) the number of opened tickets by tech. 
My goal is to get this kind of table :

```
YEAR    WEEK TECH_ID   BACKLOG_TICKETS
2017     1      5            11
2017     1      6             1
2017     1      6             0
```

But the problem is that, when a tech has no ticket in backlog (0), the record is not created, certainly because the COUNT(*) returns a null value.

So here is what I really have :
YEAR    WEEK TECH_ID   BACKLOG_TICKETS
2017     1      5            11
2017     1      6             1

and here is my request :

```
SET @selectedDate = DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2017', '%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL _week WEEK);

INSERT INTO whd_stats.backlog_tickets_by_tech_week (YEAR, WEEK, TECH_ID, BACKLOG_TICKETS_NUMBER)
    SELECT _year AS 'YEAR', _week AS 'WEEK', 
    coalesce(j.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID , 99999) AS 'TECH', 
    @backlogNumber := COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID)
    FROM whd.job_ticket j
    LEFT OUTER JOIN whd.tech t ON j.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID = t.CLIENT_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN whd.STATUS_TYPE s ON j.STATUS_TYPE_ID = s.STATUS_TYPE_ID 
    WHERE j.DELETED = 0
    -- Create Date with the given year, then add the number of week 
    AND j.REPORT_DATE <= @selectedDate 
    AND (j.CLOSE_DATE > @selectedDate
    OR (j.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL AND s.STATUS_TYPE_NAME IN ('Open', 'Pending', 'Approval Pending')))
    GROUP BY YEAR, WEEK, TECH
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE BACKLOG_TICKETS_NUMBER = @backlogNumber;
```

I have tried to replace *COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID)* by *IFNULL(COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID), 0)*, I also tried *COALESCE(COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID), 0)* but none is working, and I have no more idea...

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `COUNT(*)` does not return `NULL` values.  If nothing matches, it returns 0.  There is a big difference between a `NULL` value and not having a row in the result set.

Comment: Do a right join with a calendar help table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option here would be the "calendar table" approach.  You can create a new table looking something like this:

```
TECH_ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

You could change your query such that it begins with this calendar table and then left joins outwards.  This would guarantee that every `TECH_ID` would appear in the result set, even if it be absent in your recorded data.

Comment: Actually, when a calendar table is involved, a right join for once makes sense.

Comment: @jarlh OK, but if I reverse the join order of what you have in mind, I should end up with what I have in mind :-)  Actually, this is only half an answer, but I'm afraid to touch the OP's query.

Comment: Hi jarlh,
I'm not sure to understand what is a "calendar table"?
Do you mean a table containing all techs IDs?

Comment: @Gachdel The basic idea here is that you need to somehow bring those tech IDs into your query.  Using a formal table which contains all those IDs is one way to do this.

Comment: Hum, I see, I will try this way!

Comment: I think I'm not doing it as I should, because I still don't have all my tech in my new query :
`SELECT 2017 AS 'YEAR', 30 AS 'WEEK', 
    coalesce(tct.tech_id , 99999) AS 'TECH', COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID)
    
FROM whd.job_ticket j

LEFT OUTER JOIN whd.tech t ON j.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID = t.CLIENT_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN whd_stats.tech_calendar_table tct ON j.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID = tct.tech_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN whd.STATUS_TYPE s ON j.STATUS_TYPE_ID = s.STATUS_TYPE_ID 

WHERE blabla

GROUP BY YEAR, WEEK, TECH;`

Comment: No, you need to right join in this case: `RIGHT JOIN whd_stats.tech_calendar_table tct`

Comment: I have the same result, with RIGHT JOIN, only 52 rows, even if whd_stats.tech_calendar_table has 73 rows.
Certainly coming from my other joins...

Comment: One other thing, make the right join to the calendar table the LAST join in your query.  You have another join after this which may be filtering off records.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations Tim.
But it seems not to work :(
I don't know why, but the line when BACKLOG_TICKETS = 0 are not displayed, even with the LAST join =  RIGHT JOIN whd_stats.tech_calendar_table tct ON j.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID = tct.tech_id

Comment: One last point: You may need to move some or all of the conditions in your `WHERE` clause into the `ON` condition of the right join.  My guess now is that the `WHERE` clause is eating the missing records.  Your query is too big for me to dissect.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 IFNULL(j.JOB_TICKET_ID,0) AS ticketcount
```

Comment: OP wants 0 rows for not existing dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IF

```
IF(COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID) is NULL, 0, COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID)) as backlogNumber
```

or CASE

```
(
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID) IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID)
    END
) as backlogNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

With the (great) help of Tim, I could find a solution, using a "calendar table", containing all my tech IDs.

So here is the working request :

```
SELECT 2017 AS 'YEAR', 31 AS 'WEEK', 
tct.tech_id AS 'TECH', 
COUNT(j.JOB_TICKET_ID)
FROM whd.job_ticket j
LEFT OUTER JOIN whd.STATUS_TYPE s ON j.STATUS_TYPE_ID = s.STATUS_TYPE_ID
RIGHT JOIN whd_stats.tech_calendar_table tct ON j.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID = tct.tech_id
AND j.DELETED = 0
AND j.REPORT_DATE <= @selectedDate 
AND (j.CLOSE_DATE > @selectedDate
OR (j.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL AND s.STATUS_TYPE_NAME IN ('Open', 'Pending', 'Approval Pending')))
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

I really would like to thank Tim for learning me the "calendar table" concept and for his patience.